# Slicing a 3-Dimensional ndarray in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to slice a 3-D instance of ndarray representing a color image, where each element (or pixel) in the 2-D array contains an array with 3 bytes corresponding to the values of Red, Green, and Blue respectively. I want to slice out a 2-D ndarray for each color individually so that I can flatten them and concatenate them end-to-end as per our implementation requirements. The code I'm currently trying is...

```
red = image[:, :, 0]
green = image[:, :, 1]
blue = image[:, :, 2]
collapsed_image = numpy.concatenate((red.flatten('C'), green.flatten('C'), blue.flatten('C')), axis=0)
```

Where image is my numpy.ndarray object containing the 3-D array of bytes. Would this work to slice out each individual color's 2-D array and flatten/concatenate them together end-to-end?

Comment: You can test it yourself by setting each color 2D array to some small test array and see if the result matches what you want

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to achieve an output like this?

```
from scipy.ndimage import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

im=imread('rgb.png')
print np.shape(im)

p.subplot(121)
p.imshow(im)

red = im[:, :, 0]
green = im[:, :, 1]
blue = im[:, :, 2]
imchannels = np.concatenate((red, green, blue))

p.subplot(122)
p.imshow(imchannels)
```

Output:

```
(215L, 235L, 3L)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an [ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html) is already a flatten collection of bytes of memory, but not always in the desired order. [np.rollaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) can modify it.

As a simple example :

First a classic 2x2 image (each digit is associated to a canal):

```
image=np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)%3

In [08]: image
Out[08]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]], dtype=int32)
```

An other view, canal first :

```
bycolor= r,g,b = np.rollaxis(image,axis=2)

In [10]: bycolor
Out[10]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]]], dtype=int32)
```

and flattened layouts :

```
In [11]: image.flatten()
Out[11]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)

In [12]: bycolor.flatten()
Out[12]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

I think the last is what you want : `np.rollaxis(image,2).flatten()`